# MySQL. Left join a single matching row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: apps and images.

Each app has a many images associated with it in the images table, each image takes an enum type and there can me multiple of each type.

I want to return a single row with a single image based on the enum type.

**apps**

```
intId | strName | txtDescription
```

**images**

```
intImageId | enumImageType | strImageURL | intRelId
```

(images.intRelId = apps.intId)

I tried the following but this returned a row for every image, I just want to return a single row with the highest intImageId

```
SELECT *
FROM apps
LEFT JOIN images AS avatarTbl
    ON apps.intId = avatarTbl.intRelId 
    AND avatarTbl.enumImageType = 'avatar' 
WHERE intId = '2'
ORDER BY avatarTbl.intImageId DESC
```

Comment: add `LIMIT 1` at the end ?

Comment: @KarelG Pop the comment in the answer and I'll give you the tick

Comment: Well, if you insist ... here you go. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `LIMIT 1` at the end to return only the first row of your resultset.

```
SELECT *
FROM apps
LEFT JOIN images AS avatarTbl
    ON apps.intId = avatarTbl.intRelId 
    AND avatarTbl.enumImageType = 'avatar' 
WHERE intId = '2'
ORDER BY avatarTbl.intImageId DESC
LIMIT 1
```

good luck.